# Deserialize object of objects

Tags: .net, json

The JSON String below is provided from an api of a software we use. I do not have control on how the JSON is formatted so this is what I have to work with. I am having issues with the below JSON String on getting the class structure setup correctly. Below will be a few examples of code I have attempted. Any help would be much appreciated.

It seems to be failing on the competencies, and give the following error: {"Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path 'framework.competencies', line 1, position 169."}. I also was getting same error message for the "scale" class structure as well.

```
Dim frameworks = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of FrameWorkDetails.RootObject)(jsonString)
```

JSON:

```
{
  ""type"": ""framework"",
  ""limit"": 0,
  ""offset"": 0,
  ""total"": 9,
  ""time"": ""0.066s"",
  ""framework"": {
    ""id"": ""5228"",
    ""name"": ""CFPClassroomObservationRubric"",
    ""description"": null,
    ""competencies"": {
      ""2279-1"": {
        ""id"": ""2279-1"",
        ""code"": ""CFP1"",
        ""name"": ""TeacherIntroducesVirtue,
                  Story,
                  HistoricalBackgroundandBigQuestion"",
    ""parent"": null
  },
  ""2279-2"": {
    ""id"": ""2279-2"",
    ""code"": ""CFP2"",
    ""name"": ""CharacterFormingProcess: ExperienceIt"",
    ""parent"": null
  },
  ""2279-3"": {
    ""id"": ""2279-3"",
    ""code"": ""CFP3"",
    ""name"": ""CharacterFormingProcess: InternalizeIt(Identity)"",
    ""parent"": null
  },
  ""2279-4"": {
    ""id"": ""2279-4"",
    ""code"": ""CFP4"",
    ""name"": ""CharacterFormingProcess: InternalizeIt(Purpose)"",
    ""parent"": null
  },
  ""2279-5"": {
    ""id"": ""2279-5"",
    ""code"": ""CFP5"",
    ""name"": ""CharacterFormingProcess: InternalizeIt(Action)"",
    ""parent"": null
  },
  ""2279-6"": {
    ""id"": ""2279-6"",
    ""code"": ""CFP6"",
    ""name"": ""CharacterFormingProcess: ActivateIt"",
    ""parent"": null
  }
},
""bounds"": [

],
""scale"": {
  ""1"": ""Unsatisfactory"",
  ""2"": ""ApproachingProficient"",
  ""3"": ""Proficient"",
  ""4"": ""Mastery""
}
}
}
```

Class:

```
Public Class FrameWorkDetails

Public Class Competencies
    Public Property id As Integer
    Public Property code As String
    Public Property name As String
End Class

Public Class Bounds
    Public Property min As String
    Public Property max As String
    Public Property precision As String
End Class

Public Class Framework
    Public Property id As Integer
    Public Property name As String
    Public Property description As String
    Public Property competencies As Dictionary(Of Competencies, String)
    Public Property bounds As List(Of Bounds)
    Public Property scale As Dictionary(Of String, Double)

End Class

Public Class RootObject
    Public Property type As String
    Public Property limit As Integer
    Public Property offset As Integer
    Public Property total As Integer
    Public Property time As String
    Public Property framework As Dictionary(Of String, String)
    Public Property items_count As Integer
End Class

End Class
```

Comment: No repro. Using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json)` works fine.  What's the actual code you used? Did you use JSON.NET or another library?

Comment: Yes I am using Json.net

Comment: Dim frameworks = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of FrameWorkDetails.RootObject)(jsonString)

Comment: You defined the `framework` property as a dictionary of strings. It should be a `Framework` instead.

Comment: In Visual Studio you can generate classes for a JSON string by copying it, then selecting `Edit > Paste Special > Paste JSON as Classes`. The classes generated by this string will need a bit of tweaking, to replace multiple properties with a single Competencies dictionary

Comment: when changing to   Public Property framework As List(Of Framework). I now get "Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {""name"":""value""}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Teachboost.FrameWorkDetails+Framework]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly." & vbCrLf & "To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object.